# Rails 5 Action Controller Routing error when I remove helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error when I remove a helper for a corresponding controller:

```
Couldn't find CompaniesHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/companies_helper.rb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I am confused by this as I didn't think the companies_controller was dependent on having a helper. Maybe I am wrong in this assumption?

I have tried in my `development.rb` to remove including the helpers which hasn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT**

Full stack trace:

```
Rails.root: /Users/Richard/Code/whisper

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:162:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:155:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:94:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:186:in `default_helper_module!'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:35:in `block in inherited'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:35:in `class_eval'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:35:in `inherited'
actionview (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_view/layouts.rb:219:in `inherited'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:23:in `inherited'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/parameter_encoding.rb:10:in `inherited'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:237:in `inherited'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in with'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:7:in `inherited'
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:653:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:467:in `load_file'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:365:in `block in require_or_load'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
bootsnap (1.3.2) lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:193:in `const_missing'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:574:in `get'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:605:in `constantize'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:88:in `controller_class_for'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:81:in `controller_class'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:46:in `controller'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
webpacker (3.5.5) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:22:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.2.0.rc2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Do you have `include CompaniesHelper` line in the controller file? If yes, just remove it

Comment: thanks for your reply, I haven't included it in my controller nor the application controller.

Comment: Did you check carefully name of helper? Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: @user3927582 Could you please add full error stacktrace, not only the first line?

Comment: @Vasilisa I have edited the answer to include the full stack trace. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3927582 Did you try to stop rails server and run `spring stop && rails server`?

Comment: I still get the same error. I've created multiple controllers and all get the same error. For example, I have a claims_controller and when I navigate to /claims I get the same error, `Couldn't find ClaimsHelper, expected it to be defined in helpers/claims_helper.rb`

Comment: @user3927582 Try to grep `helper` word in your project, maybe you find something. I have no idea why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5+, *By default, each controller will include all helpers.*

Pre Rails 5, the controller would include a helper matched to its name. Making the setting as specified above returns to the Pre-Rails 5 behavior.

To set Pre-Rails-5 behaviour of helpers, set in config/development.rb

```
 config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```